# Different static image per zoom level with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, dictionary, static, openlayers

Seeking an opportunity with OpenLayers to display per zoom level a custom static graphic. As an example, for two zoom levels I need two different graphics. Can anyone help me further? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Either write custom JavaScript by getting the zoom of the map programmatically or maybe you can do something using rules: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Styles#AdvancedRule-basedStyling